# IEnumerable<T> - How to use one method for both enumerators

Tags: c#, enumeration

This is probably a silly question but I haven't found the answer to it anywhere.

I have a simple class that implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Line>>`. It's a base class for a file reader that reads EFT flat files we received from a bank.

Derived classes implement the abstract `GetNext` method that you see in the code, and return a Line-derived type, depending on the type of line they read. Originally I had the callers of derived readers call `GetNext` in  a loop until EOF, when they return null. With an enumerator, they can call foreach instead, and loop through the reader.

But why do I have to implement two enumerators? Both do exactly the same thing. And I can't refactor it to call the same method via right click => Refactor => Extract Method, because the method contains a **`yield`** statement. But surely I *can* use a single helper method for both? What would the signature of such a method be?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace EasyDebit.BankInterface
{
    public abstract class FileReader : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Line>>
    {
        protected int current;
        protected List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        private string filename;

        public FileReader(string filename)
        {
            this.filename = filename;
            this.lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList();
        }

        public string Filename
        {
            get { return filename; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, Line>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            Line line = null;
            current = 0;

            while ((line = GetNext()) != null)
                yield return new KeyValuePair<int, Line>(current, line);
        }

        public abstract Line GetNext();

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            Line line = null;
            current = 0;

            while ((line = GetNext()) != null)
                yield return new KeyValuePair<int, Line>(current, line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply cast it to eliminate the duplicate code.

```
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, Line>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Line line = null;
        current = 0;

        while ((line = GetNext()) != null)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<int, Line>(current, line);
    }

    public abstract Line GetNext();

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Comment: The cast is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks very much. It works fine. (without the typecast as noted above)